# Oracle Regular Expression to match US Phone Number Format

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-like

Oracle Regular Expression To match US Phone Number in the following formats only.

`(NNN) NNN-NNNN` or `NNN-NNN-NNNN` or `NNNNNNNNNN`

I have tried and came up to this :

```
with test as
(
select '(444) 123-6780' as testcol from dual
union
select '444123-6780'                from dual
union
select '6741236780'                from dual
union
select '(445) 123-6781'            from dual
union
select '447-127-6787'            from dual
union
select '447-127-3333333333'            from dual
)
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(testcol, '^\(?\d{3}\)?([[:blank:]|-])?\d{3}-?\d{4}$');
```

Results :

```
(444) 123-6780  -- valid
(445) 123-6781  -- valid
444123-6780     -- not valid
447-127-6787    -- valid
6741236780      -- valid
```

As you can see, I received `444123-6780` (`NNNNNN-NNNN`) format,
which I don't require.

Is there any way to stop the above mentioned format not to match?

Comment: Interestingly, none of your numbers are valid North American phone numbers because the first and fourth digits cannot be 1's. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan

Answer (score 1):

```
REGEXP_LIKE(testcol,'^(\(\d{3}\))([[:blank:]])\d{3}-\d{4}$|^\d{3}(-)\d{3}(-)\d{4}$|^\d{10}$')
```

Comment: I thought it could be done with a single regex string ;)... But because of `([[:blank:]|-])?` the earlier regex will match a string having format `NNNNNN-NNNN [444123-6780]` which is not required. So , I made regex string for each format and, `OR` them together

Answer (score 0):

try this reg ex.. it will help you

```
REGEXP_LIKE(testcol,'^\([0-9]{3}\)[:space:]?[0-9]{3}(-|[:space:])?[0-9]{4}$|^[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}$')
```

Source From : http://psoug.org/snippet/Regular-Expressions--RegExp-examples-3_859.htm